# In every of the $N$ boxes there are $n$ white and $m$ black balls. From the first a ball is taken and put into the second..

Tags: probability

and lastly from the n-th a ball is taken. What is the probability that the ball is white? Answer: The hypotheses are

$H_1$- the first drawn is white and last is white.

$H_2$- the first drawn is white and last black.

$H_3$- the first drawn is black and last black.

$H_4$- the first drawn is black and last white.

Then it says P($H_2$)=P($H_4$) Because a bijection can be formed between the two. This I understand , what I dont understand is the final answer which is $$P(A)= \frac{1}{m+n}(nP(H_1)+(n-1)P(H_2)+nP(H_3)+(n+1)P(H_4))=...={n \over {m+n}}$$

Honestly the answer isnt too visible, so this is probabily a typo, if anyone can put together an answer from this I would appreciate that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know what's going on with all those $H$'s. Anyway, here's my solution:

Let $B_i$ be the event that the $i$th ball drawn is black. We are looking for $\mathbb{P}(B_n)$. Intuitively, $\mathbb{P}(B_n)$ should be $\frac{m}{m+n}$, since there is no reason for it to be biased toward black or white from this probability.

$\mathbb{P}(B_i)$ depends only on whether $B_{i-1}$ occurred or not.
$$\mathbb{P}(B_i) = \mathbb{P}(B_i \mid B_{i-1}) \mathbb{P}(B_{i-1}) + \mathbb{P}(B_i \mid B_{i-1}^c) \mathbb{P}(B_{i-1}^c),$$
by the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). This suggests an induction proof. If we calculate $\mathbb{P}(B_2)$, we get
 $$\mathbb{P}(B_2) = \mathbb{P}(B_2 \mid B_{1}) \mathbb{P}(B_{1}) + \mathbb{P}(B_2 \mid B_{1}^c) \mathbb{P}(B_{1}^c)$$ 
$$=\frac{m+1}{m+n+1}\frac{m}{m+n} + \frac{m}{m+n+1}\frac{n}{m+n}$$
$$=\frac{m^2 + m + mn}{(m+n+1)(m+n)}=\frac{m}{m+n}.$$

So $\mathbb{P}(B_2) = \mathbb{P}(B_1)$, and then $\mathbb{P}(B_3) = \mathbb{P}(B_2) = \mathbb{P}(B_1)$, etc. By induction, $\mathbb{P}(B_{n})=\frac{m}{m+n}$.